# Python: Strip off string quotes from binary number

Tags: python, python-2.7

so i have t= 111

```
bin(1111)
Out[105]: '0b10001010111'
```

and

```
g = bin(111)

g
Out[16]: '0b1101111'
```

My question is, is there away to strip the quotes. I am concerned with performing arithmetic operation over it.

like g = g -0b1 , etc in an iteration.

**UPDATE**

I just wanted for eg, g = bin(111)[2:] to be 1101111 not '1101111' in qoutations.

Anyway did a very simple workaround instead taking in the binary number and operating over it.

```
    length = len(string) #what is the len of this string
    t = startrange #Equivalent to binary string, i.e. for 111 it is 7
    for i in range(int(startrange)):
        t -= 1
        l=tuple((bin(t)[2:].zfill(length)))
```

PS: But as in iteration bin() conversion happens everytime. not that it is a serious performance issue.

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do here.  `bin` returns a string.  How do you plan on using that string exactly?

Comment: so for `bin(111)` you want to return the integer `1101111`?

Comment: added an update. @RyanSaxe

Answer (score 3):

Only use `bin` when you want to convert the number to a string.

Any integer is already bits inside the computer, no need to "convert" it in order to perform any arithmetic operations.

Do any calculation with integer values and convert the result to the format you need only for output.

Comment: yeah that's what i did. just to keep the whole bin(x) string o/p fixed length added zfill

Comment: @user2290820: you can use `format(x, '016b')` do do it in one pass (replace 16 with the length you want).

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for and/or what you're doing doesn't make a lot of sense. The `bin` function returns a string, so it's always going to "have" quotes. If you want to do arithmetic with the number, you need to just use it as a number (which you already have access to before calling `bin`). Once your calculations are done, you can use `bin` to format the result in binary.

Unless, you're trying to do the binary calculations by hand that the machine would normally be doing for you. Then you could do something like this:

```
number = 111
bits = [int(b) for b in bin(number)[2:]] # get a list of "bits"
print(bits) # Prints [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Then you could manually do your bit operations, I guess.

**Edit** as Jon Clements mentions, you can do this a little more cleanly with `map` and the `format` function (formatting to `'b'` for the Binary format spec) instead of the `bin` function that you were using:

```
number = 111
bits = map(int, format(number, 'b')) # get a list of "bits"
print(bits) # Prints [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: @Henry it's a great company you're working in. i love that kind of work. i tried many such silly workarounds. but i guess the simple workaround i found useful for my module is in the update. as everybody here is saying.plain and simple

Answer (score 0):

Just print it:

```
>>> print bin(1111)
0b10001010111
```

You don't actually have the quotes there, it's just your python "shell" that attach them to the output to "help" you

Answer (score 0):

If you must go to a binary string, and then do calculations with it, simply:

```
binary_string = bin(111)

num_to_calc_with = int(binary_string, base=2)
```

Comment: Which means you end up with the input to `bin` - so err, it's effectively a no-op ;)

Comment: Agreed! But maybe he wants to convert to binary strings, store them in a list somewhere, and then convert back later. I don't know, man, his question ;)

Answer (score -2):

As people have said, you don't really need to do this at all, but the following will give you your binary number as an integer if that's what you want:

```
int(bin(111)[2::])
```